# MySQLi and PHP: stop automatically escaping apostrophes

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a form that I use in my CPanel. When I enter data into the form with apostrophes or quotes, such as:

> There's an example

It is saved in my database as:

> There\'s an example

---

I don't understand why the quotes are being escaped automatically.

- I don't have anything set to escape the posted data
- It is updated using a prepared statement
- Magic quotes are off (gpc, runtime, and sybase)

Here is my PHP code that updates the database:

```
<?php

include "{$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]}/global/php/db.mysqli.php";

$title = $_POST["title"];
$subtitle = $_POST["subtitle"];
$dir = $_POST["dir"];
$parts = $_POST["parts"];
$override = $_POST["override"];

if($override == "true" || $override == true)
    $override = 1;
else
    $override = 0;

$stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE ... SET `title`=?, `subtitle`=?, `dir`=?, `parts`=?, `override`=? WHERE `id`=? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $title, $subtitle, $dir, $parts, $override, $id);
$stmt->execute();

?>
```

Comment: @Gumbo sometimes it's good to read the question body

Comment: I suggest you `var_dump($_POST)` before *and* after you include db.mysqli.php.

Comment: Magic quotes are off, you say? Interesting... Hmm... And have you confirmed this by `var_dump`ing the relevant functions to tell you this? Otherwise it might be that PHP is loading a different config file to the one you're expecting.

Comment: Sometimes question body shouldn't be trusted. We all know the reasons for the extra slashes. They are scarce and already known. There is *nothing* new.

Comment: @OP, you have but a simple choice: either these slashes being added by magic or one of your premises are wrong. Choose one and then investigate it. Community hardly can help you with it.

Comment: My bet - some sort of "sanitize them all" function that is lurking somewhere in the legacy code

Comment: @YourCommonSense Not to interrupt your rant, but my suggestion is actually quite a likely thing to bite one's arse ;)